# Browser loading saved username/password after javascript validation runs

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have some javascript that validates some user inputs in real time and provides visual feedback for the user BEFORE the form is sent. It also disables the login box until the validation criteria is met.

My problem is that (Particularly with log in inputs), if the browser saves a username and password, it re-enters these details into the inputs automatically, but my javascript runs before the browser loads these values. This means that my code is validating a blank box and then chrome is filling in the details. This leaves the correct details and a login form that has a disabled log in button (Until the user changes the inputs)

My javascript at the moment validates each box on pageload and on keyup.

How can I get the validation code to run AFTER the browser loads the saved details?

Comment: http://furrybrains.com/2009/01/02/capturing-autofill-as-a-change-event/

Comment: Why validate on pageload in the first place?

Comment: Because the boxes have values in them on pageload if the user submits an incorrect password or if they push a back button